# Adding a colum to databound DevExpress ASPxTreeList

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I would like to add a column from behind code to a data bound ASPxTreeList . The column i wanted to add is always is the first column before the datafield of my table.

I manually set the visible index=0 but the datafield of my table having the visibleIndex=0 as well , so the layout of the result of the unbound column will be displayed as second column instead of first.

Is that anyway to always make sure the unbound column i added is always at the first column even with the databound ASPxTreeList?

The similar situation just like setting the SettingsSelection.Enabled=true , then the checkbox column will be shown at the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inserting column with [Columns.Insert](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListTreeListColumnCollection_Inserttopic): `treeList.Columns.Insert(0, column)`
**EDIT:**  I tested my solution and this is conclusion:
`Columns.Insert` and `column.VisibleIndex = 0` works.
`Columns.Add` and `column.VisibleIndex = 0` doesn't work.

```
protected void treeList_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeListTextColumn column = new TreeListTextColumn {Name = "Unbound", VisibleIndex = 0};
    // works 
    treeList.Columns.Insert(0, column);
    // doesn't work
    //treeList.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: The insert method only make affect on the treelist.columncollection index but not the visible index. What i just figured and done is i using forloop to for into the visibleColumn and change their visible index+1 then assign my unbound column visibleIndex=0.
Thank for the suggestion,Filip.